# SAML POST /saml/SSO redirecting to IP address rather DNS name

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am creating SAML service provider using spring-boot as auth0 as IDP and deployed on server.
Everything, work as expected with IP address. But when I use, DNS name things getting started failing.

Here is my code,

```
http
          .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
          .apply(SAMLConfigurer.saml())
              .serviceProvider()
                  .keyStore()
                      .storeFilePath(this.keyStoreFilePath)
                      .password(this.password)
                      .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                      .keyPassword(this.password)
                      .and()
                  .protocol("https")
                  .hostname("www.myserverdns.con")
                  .basePath("/")
                  .and()
              .identityProvider()
              .metadataFilePath("file:"+resource);
```

So, when I hit "www.myserverdns.con/someAPI", call goes to "www.myserverdns.con/saml/SSO" and server redirects to "serverIP.address/someAPI".

Here is a output got from SAML tracer,

```
POST https://www.assesshub.com/assessws/saml/SSO HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302
Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2020 13:34:02 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://serverIP.address:8080/someAPI
```

Note: as I said, above code is working fine with IP address but having problem only when using DNS name.

Additionally here is log of application,

```
2020-11-18 18:59:49.615  INFO 31467 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;serverIP.address;https://server.dns.name/saml/metadata;urn:dev-***.us.auth0.com;;;
2020-11-18 19:04:01.251  INFO 31467 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;serverIP.address;https:/server.dns.name/saml/metadata;urn:dev-***.us.auth0.com;;;
2020-11-18 19:04:02.058  INFO 31467 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] colMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule : SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing
2020-11-18 19:04:02.064  INFO 31467 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNResponse;SUCCESS;serverIP.address;https://server.dns.name/saml/metadata;urn:dev-***.us.auth0.com;auth0|5fac201d954ba3006f0a39c2;;
```

What I have tried,

1. As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e1940, I checked `entityBaseURL` but its not working

Can someone give input?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think this is not related to Spring SAML as such. I wonder how the whole "HTTP request flow" looks like. Is there a 'RelayState' parameter in the play? If not, then the 'return URL' is stored in 'memory' on Spring side and then used to contruct the 'Location' header.

Comment: >Is there a 'RelayState' parameter in the play? If not, then the 'return URL' is stored in 'memory' 
I have not set any other parameter. When you say "memory", could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Spring SAML caches this in the HTTP session.

Comment: @ShaunakPatel I am experiencing the same issue that you're encountered. Have you found any fixes on this?